# Как делается хороший поиск на сайте с нахождением по разным формам слова

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Скажите как делается например [такой поиск](http://www.tks.ru/cgi-bin/search.cgi?q=%F2%E0%EC%EE%E6%E5%ED%ED%FB%E5+%EF%EB%E0%F2%E5%E6%E8&s=DRP)

В поиск вбивается "таможенные платежи". А находит статьи с разными вариантами вхождения слова "таможенный" - таможенную, таможенной. Ну как поиск от гугла и яндекса, только на своем сайте.

Может поисковая строка анализируется сначала, определяются возможные формы слов (откуда кстати взять эту инфу) и к БД идет уже запрос по всем вариантам?

Или наоборот, когда индекс слов составляется, определяется базовое слово, от склоненных?

Comment: [Какой алгоритм лучше всего использовать для поиска в тексте?][1] 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/159793/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=159800#159800

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека она называется `phpMorphy`, которая пишет словоформы. Вот пример как она работает: [Демонстрация работы `phpMorphy`](http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/demo?word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8&dict_type=aot&enable_predict_by_suffix=1&enable_predict_by_db=1)

В общем делаем словоформы, иногда вообще оставляют только корень слова и начинают искать в базе.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще заюзать [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) на базе Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

Так и воспользуйся поиском от Гугла или Яндекса на своем сайте. Они предостовляют такую возможность. Можно еще и на рекламе заработать при желаний. Это самый простой и быстрый способ.